# Is there a way to join all the values from a multi-select lookup table question with commas in a label?

Tags: commcare

I have a multi-select question that pulls its values from a lookup table. Once the user has selected some of these options, I want to show them to the user in a comma-separated list.

The lookup table has a 'value' column, which is a snake_case version of the 'name' column which has a human-readable version of the item the user is selecting.

I would like to display the human-readable version of all of the items the user has selected in a label.

I've tried 2 approaches:

1) set the 'value field' of the lookup table question to be the 'name' column then use `replace(/path/to/question, " ", ", ")` to show the results comma separated. Unfortunately this doesn't work because some of the names have spaces in them, and these are getting replaced by commas.

2) Use a repeat group to loop over each of the selected items in the question and compile a label using `selected-at(/path-to-question/, position(..))`. This doesn't work because the label doesn't update if the user deselects options they previously selected.

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to change how the values are stored int he lookup table? If you could change the spaces in the values to `"_"` you'd be able to use replace as you want to. I think it's bad practice to store spaces as values anyway ... when you export that data you'll have the same issue with separating out the responses.

If you change to `"_"` in your data you should be able to nest the replaces to display the values without `"_"'s` to the users:

```
replace(replace(path/to/question, " ", ","), "_", " ")
```

That would convert:

"option_1 option_2 option_3" 
to 
"option 1, option 2, option 3."